# Simple sqlite query with ascending order

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im working with QT and using sqlite. When I write this:

```
QSqlQuery q = db_.exec("SLECT *"
                       "From history;");
```

It works as expected, but with this I got nothing:

```
QSqlQuery q = db_.exec("SLECT *"
                       "From history"
                       "ORDER BY id ASC;");
```

This is the table creation:

```
db_.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history ("
          "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"
          "url TEXT,"
          "day REAL,"
          "month REAL,"
          "year REAL,"
          "hour REAL,"
          "minute REAL,"
          "second REAL"
          ");");
```

Thanks

Comment: You sure any one of them works both have `SLECT `  in them missing `E` post your actual query.

Comment: Yes its weird but I got all the items with "SLECT". Anyway I only have one table so maybe what sqlite interprets is -> db_.exec(" "); and it just give me all.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `SELECT` missing an `E`, you may also need whitespace characters between `*` and `From`, and between `history` and `ORDER` - try:

```
QSqlQuery q = db_.exec("SELECT * "
                       "From history "
                       "ORDER BY id ASC;");
```

Comment: Spaces around `*` are not actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in `SLECT`, should be `SELECT`. Other syntax seems to be fine.

Comment: Such a big fail... Thanks